# Java TreeSet - How to efficiently insert then poll immediate neighbors?

Tags: java

**Looking for a solution that would work on stock Java 8, no libraries.**

I'm trying to implement the standard Line Segment intersection algorithm.  This involves keeping track of a sorted collection (on y-coordinate) of Line Segments currently "active".

Part of the algorithm is, assuming a TreeSet `actives` and a new line Segment `s`:

- insert `s` into `actives`
- lookup the immediate neighbors of `s` in `actives` and do some math

I've implemented this as:

```
// left neighbor of s, as though already added
try {
    Segment sa = actives.tailSet(s).first();
    if (math(sa, s) {
        ...
    }
} catch(NoSuchElementException ignore) {}
// right neighbor versus s, as though already added
try {
    Segment sb = actives.headSet(s).last();
    if (math(sb, s) {
        ...
    }
} catch(NoSuchElementException ignore) {}   

// add s => actives
actives.add(s);
```

Aside from the aggravating try/catch in case `first()` or `last()` fails (which is a trade off against first getting the subset in a variable, THEN checking if it's empty, THEN proceeding if not), the real problem, as I understand it, is this is inefficient, namely:

`tailSet()`, `headSet()`, and `add()` all incur O(log(N)) work on my TreeSet `actives`, while the algorithm assumes I can insert once in O(log(N)), and then look up neighbors in O(1).

How can I do something similar, but incur the O(log(N)) binary lookup only once?  I'm doing 3x as much work as necessary.

Comment: `Successor`/`predecessor` methods are package private to `TreeMap`. I don't think they can be called from outside their package even by a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try adding the element `s` to `actives` first, then calling `actives.lower(s)` and `actives.higher(s)`. The `TreeSet` docs don't state the complexity of those methods but they look O(1) to me in the source code.

Comment: This may depend on jdk.  I (think I) traced to http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/TreeMap-source.html and found it calling `highestLessThan()` with O(log(N)) tree traversal.  Can you link to source showing O(1) if key is already present?

Comment: I checked the backing code for `higher`/`lower`, and they are not strictly `O(1)`. They are `O(ln(n))`, because the tree needs to be walked vertically once, and the height of the tree grows in `O(ln(n))`.

Comment: @jdowdell JDK 1.8 has TreeSet backed by TreeMap, and TreeMap's `getLowerEntry`/`getHigherEntry` have a logarithmic runtime. But this still a very quick way to access neighboring elements!

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code a bit:

```java
// left neighbor of s, as though already added
SortedSet<Segment> trailSet = actives.tailSet(s);
if (!trailSet.isEmpty()) {
    Segment sa = trailSet.first();
    if (math(sa, s) {
        ...
    }
}

// right neighbor versus s, as though already added
SortedSet<Segment> headSet = actives.headSet(s);
if (!headSet.isEmpty()) {
    Segment sb = headSet.last();
    if (math(sb, s) {
        ...
    }
}

// add s => actives
actives.add(s);
```

There is no need to catch anything (as you can check emptieness ahead of retrieving the first (or last) element). This is more performant, as it does not cause stack trace generation.

But you can even go with something better. According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html , you can call a method that

> Returns the greatest element in this set strictly less than the given element, or null if there is no such element.

or the smallest, strictly greater. **The methods are called `lower` and `higher`.**

```java
Segment sa = actives.higher(s);
if (sa != null && math(sa, s) {
    ...
}

// right neighbor versus s, as though already added
Segment sb = actives.lower(s);
if (sb != null && math(sb, s) {
    ...
}

// add s => actives
actives.add(s);
```